# Single request header length exceeds configures maximum

Tags: java, servlets

I'm developing a web application using JSP, Struts and I'm deploying it to an OC4J server. I have created a simple JSP page with two buttons.

Mi problem is that when I click on any of the buttons, I got an error message stating that that *"Single request header length exceeds configured maximum"*. What causes this error message? What should I change in the configuration?

Please help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think it Denial Of Service enabled on your server. By default every server sets the following limits:

- maximum single header size
- maximum header size (sum of all headers)

[Look here for the documentation which explains about this. Try increasing the values.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16764_01/web.1111/e10143/security.htm#CDDBCBCE)